# Why is getting a member faster than calling hasOwnProperty?

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm writing a JS object that needs to perform really basic key-value caching on string:function pairs. The class runs on the client and caches partially-compiled templates for rendering part of the page, so it may have anywhere from 20-200 items.

Before actually writing the class, I figured it would be a good idea to see what the fastest cache retrieval method was. The options that came to mind were:

**1. Basic property access:**

```
if (x[k] !== undefined) {
    v = x[k];
}
```

**2. Key Check (Own):**

```
if (x.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    v = x[k];
}
```

**3. Key Check (General):**

```
if (k in x) {
    v = x[k];
}
```

I assumed that 3 would be fastest (checks to see if the property exists but doesn't retrieve it or worry about where it exists) and 1 would be slowest (actually gets the property, even if it doesn't do anything).

[Putting all of these into jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/double-lookup) yielded some very strange results. In both Chrome (and Chromium) and IE, #1 is about twice as fast. In Firefox, #3 has a minor edge, but performance is similar between all three. It didn't matter if I was running in a VM or not, and didn't change a lot between versions.

I'm having trouble explaining these results. It might be that #1 notices that nothing will happen to the data and so just checks for the key internally, but why is it faster than #3? Why does #3 not get the same optimization?

What is causing these results? Is there some JIT optimization I might be hitting that skews the data?

More importantly, why is this so drastically different between browsers, with all options being roughly equal in FF?

Comment: You know that objects are compiled as [classes in V8 with enough consistency in property accesses](https://developers.google.com/v8/design) ? *BTW I'm trying to summon here an expert in jsperf debunking, Pekta, come please...*

Comment: As a completely unscientific assumption, my guess would be option 1 (or variations of 1) are likely the most common use case, hence more effort may have been spent optimizing for that particular usage.

Comment: @dystroy That makes perfectly good sense and explains what I'm seeing pretty well, especially if you assume the compiler is smart enough to throw away the results (or keep them for the next line). I'm more curious as to why the others are so much slower and/or why it varies so much between browsers. Does it not keep around a list of what properties are in the class it built? Does that means a `for in` would have to reflect out all the properties every time?

Comment: @Carl Yes, that's basically what's written in the document I linked to. Basic property access is optimized in classes (until the assumptions of the optimizer are proven wrong).

Comment: It's also worth noting that this should be an academic question - don't prematurely optimise things like this. I assure you your bottleneck will be elsewhere (until proven otherwise).

Comment: @Zirak The bottleneck will absolutely be loading and pre-compiling the templates, I have no real doubts about that. This was just an idle question, until it yielded some funny results. Now I'm curious. ;)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The secret behind `x[k]` performance on Chrome (V8) is in [this chunk of assembly from `ic-ia32.cc`](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/210ff4af7a3537dc1ce19a58abf6d7105991f527/src/ia32/ic-ia32.cc#L475-L565). In short: V8 maintains a global cache that maps a pair of `(map, name)` to an `index` specifying location of the property. *Map* is an internal name used in V8 for *hidden classes* other JS engines call them differently (*shapes* in SpiderMonkey and *structures* in JavaScriptCore). This cache is populated only for own properties of fast mode objects. Fast mode is the representation of an object that does not use dictionary to store properties, but instead is more like a C-structure with properties occupying fixed offsets.

As you can see once the cache is populated the fist time your loop is executed, it will always be hit on the subsequent repetitions, meaning that the property lookup will always be handled inside the generated code and will never enter runtime because all properties benchmark is looking up actually exist on the object. If you profile the code you will see the following line:

```
256   31.8%   31.8%  KeyedLoadIC: A keyed load IC from the snapshot
```

and dumping native code counters would show this (actual number depends on the number of iterations you repeat the benchmark):

```
| c:V8.KeyedLoadGenericLookupCache                               |    41999967 |
```

which illustrates that cache is indeed being hit.

Now V8 does not actually use the same cache for either `x.hasOwnProperty(k)` or `k in x`, in fact it does not use any cache and always end up calling runtime, e.g. in the profile for `hasOwnProperty` case you will see a lot of C++ methods:

```
339   17.0%   17.0%  _ZN2v88internal8JSObject28LocalLookupRealNamedPropertyEPNS0_4NameEPNS0_12LookupResultE.constprop.635
254   12.7%   12.7%  v8::internal::Runtime_HasLocalProperty(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
156    7.8%    7.8%  v8::internal::JSObject::HasRealNamedProperty(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>)
134    6.7%    6.7%  v8::internal::Runtime_IsJSProxy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
 71    3.6%    3.6%  int v8::internal::Search<(v8::internal::SearchMode)1, v8::internal::DescriptorArray>(v8::internal::DescriptorArray*, v8::internal::Name*, int)
```

and the main problem here is not even that these are C++ methods and not handwritten assembly (like KeyedLoadIC stub) but that these methods are performing the same lookup again and again without caching the outcome.

Now the implementations can be wildly different between engines, so unfortunately I can't give complete explanation of what happens on other engines, but my guess would be that any engine that shows faster `x[k]` performance is employing similar cache (or represents `x` as a dictionary, which would also allow fast probing in the generated code) and any engine that shows equivalent performance between cases either does not use any caching or employs that same cache for all three operations (which would make perfect sense).

If V8 probed the same cache before going to runtime for `hasOwnProperty` and `in` then on your benchmark you would have seen equivalent performance between cases.

Comment: You should blog about that (responding to your comment in the deleted post) - I'd be very interested in reading. The amount of information about engine internals is a bit scarce and we're all interested :) Your site is also down by the way. (Also, here is the link about object representation in v8 if anyone is interested http://www.jayconrod.com/posts/52/a-tour-of-v8-object-representation )

Comment: I confirm we're many ones interested. The V8 blog post we always cite is too sparse on details or even practical tips.

Comment: This is pretty clever, particularly how they appear to store multiple optimized classes. Makes perfectly good sense, too. I'd be interested in what other optimizations like this occur, because the fastest code is definitely not the most intuitive here.

Comment: @ssube the question is of course what *fastest* means in this context.  as I have mentioned above very good performance of `x[k]` is a by product of the fact that benchmark always hits the cache once it is populated. This does not necessarily reflect your real world use case, e.g. if I make benchmark where we lookup no-existent property 50% of time then picture changed and hasOwnProperty comes at the top because it does less stuff and only looks at own properties: http://jsperf.com/double-lookup/2

Comment: @ssube now if I change `x` object to become a *dictionary mode* object (which is most likely if you are using it as a cache) then picture changes once again http://jsperf.com/double-lookup/3 Overall it is very hard to write a meaningful microbenchmark against the sophisticated system like V8 which is literally overflawing with different tricks in heuristics. You should base benchmark on your real world use case as close as possible.

Comment: @VyacheslavEgorov: You should include that last comment in your answer to hightlight it better :-)